# add data from client side javascript to server side file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, vb.net

I do not know how save three variables (firstName, lastName, sectionName) to a file on the server from my javascript in the html file.  I do not know what needs to be in the javascript code, and in the server file, to print this information on a file on the server.

I am trying to create a 2 question math quiz that will check a response, and record student information information on the server so I can record their grade.
So far, I have an index.html file where user enters their name and selects a quiz; a section 1.1.html file that contains the quiz, and javascript to check their answers  when clicking the submit button; and a studentList file that I want firstName, lastName, and sectionName recorded to on the server side.

In the 1.1.html file, Everything works as far as generating numbers, checking answers, and displaying results to the user, however I cannot figure out how to store firstName, lastName, and sectionName (variables declared globally in the script and retrieved using localStorage from the index.html page) on the server.  Here is the code that isn't working (note that if I remove the $.post() the code works up to the point of printing to a file on the server).;

between script tags in the html file:

```
function getScore(form) {
  //format answers in answer blank 1
  form.elements[0].value = form.elements[0].value.toUpperCase();
  form.elements[0].value = form.elements[0].value.replace(/\s/g, "");
  score=0;
  for (i=0; i<numQues; i++) {
    if (form.elements[i].value == answers[i]) {
      score++;
    }
  }
  score = Math.round(score/numQues*100);
  if (score == 100){
    response = confirm("Congratulations, you received a 100%")
    //record name and quiz number into file
    //jquery AJAX
    $.post(studentFileName,
    {
      firstname: firstName
      lastname: lastName
      sectionname: sectionName
    });
  } else{
    response = confirm("You received a " + score + "%.  Please try again")
    if (response == true) {
      //reset page with new numbers.
      window.location.reload();
    } else {
      //take to main page
      window.location.href = "index.html";
    }
  }
}
```

here is the body of the html code

```
<body onload="getRandomNum(this.form); getStudent(this.form)">
<form name="quiz">
1. Write an expression for distance (D) traveled by an airplane <i>in terms of</i> it's speed (S) and time (T).  Use only the letters D, S, and T along with any operations you need such as =, +, -, *, /, etc.<br>
<input type="text" name="q1" size=15 value="">
<p>

2. Evaluate the expression (t - 6)<sup>2</sup> + 12 &divide 3 - 7 for<div id="randNum"> </div> 
<br>

<input type="text" name="q2" size=15 value="">
<p>

<input type="button" value="Get score" onClick="getScore(this.form)">
<input type="reset" value="Clear"><p>
</form>
```

and here is the `studentFileName` document (1.1.htmlList.asp)

```
<%
dim fname, lname, section
fname = Request.Form(firstName)
lname = Request.Form(lastName)
section = Request.Form(sectionName)
Response.Write(lname & ", " & fname & ", " & section)
%>
```

Comment: "doesn't record the results" — Why would it *record* the results? Your VB just writes some data from the request back to the response. It doesn't record it anywhere, and your JavaScript doesn't do anything with the response.

Comment: You really should run http://jshint.com/ over that code. So many unnecessary globals.

Comment: Also `<body onload="getRandomNum(this.form); getStudent(this.form)">` is bad form. Instead give the form an ID and use `window.onload=function() { var form = document.getElementById('quiz'); getRandomNum(form); getStudent(form)}` or seeing you use jQuery = `$(function() {var form = $('#quiz').get(0); getRandomNum(form); getStudent(form)}});`

Comment: @Quentin, thanks for the tip on jshint.com.  Big help, and I'll keep that in mind in the future.  As you can tell this is all new to me; my background is in VB and C++.  Also, I understand that it doesn't record the results.  How do I modify the response.write() so it records lastName, firstName, and sectionName into a file on the server?

Comment: @mplungjan I made the changes in javascript.  Thanks for the tip on proper form.